# Is there an infinite version of the brute-force lattice congruence representation algorithm that succeeds?

Tags: abstract-algebra, order-theory, lattice-orders, universal-algebra

I am interested in the congruence lattices of algebraic structures.

Is there a brute-force way to produce an **infinite** algebraic structure whose lattice of congruences is isomorphic to some given finite lattice?

---

[This MO post by Noah Schweber](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/442104/example-of-trickiness-of-finite-lattice-representation-problem) describes a brute force algorithm for building a finite algebraic structure with a given congruence lattice that **doesn't succeed**.

Namely, starting with a finite lattice $\Lambda$, you represent it as a set of partitions of some finite set $X$ **picked in some unspecified manner** that is order-isomorphic to $\Lambda$; call it $\Lambda((X))$.

Next, you create a new algebraic structure with domain $X$ that is endowed with **every function that is well-defined when modded out by every partition associated with $X$**; call this structure $\Lambda(X)$.

$\Lambda(X)$ is a [clone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clone_(algebra)); it has projections and is closed under composition.

There are a few things about this construction that I don't understand, but I'm willing to accept that it breaks in an instructive way on faith:

1. How did we choose $X$?
2. If $\Lambda$ is the congruence lattice of some finite algebra $A$, it certainly seems like we could **extend $A$ with all functions that respect its congruences** and end up with a clone $\Lambda(X)$ for some finite $X$ equipped with a set of partitions.

The fact that this fails for **finite sets $X$** makes me wonder if there's a construction using **infinite sets** that succeeds.

Comment: Re: understanding the finite situation, I think it would be instructive to play with Keith Kearnes' example of $M_4$. This lattice embeds into $Part(5)$, but isn't the congruence lattice of any algebra of size $<6$. Basically, this means that $X=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ "looks safe" in that we can find an embedding $\eta$ of $M_4$ into $Part(X)$, but the resulting greedy algebra we build has *too big* a lattice of congruences - there aren't enough functions on $X$ to kill off all equivalence relations *not* in the image of $\eta$. Make $X$ bigger, though, and we get "enough room" to not overshoot $M_4$.

Comment: Meanwhile, Gratzer/Schmidt's paper solving the infinite base set case is available at [the Acta site](http://pub.acta.hu/acta/showCustomerArticle.action?id=7248&dataObjectType=article&returnAction=showCustomerVolume&sessionDataSetId=7c5af34c61c7aa17&style=), but actually a later paper by Pudlak [*(A new proof of the congruence lattice representation theorem)*](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF02485835) sounds like it might be more along the lines of what you're looking for.

Comment: I haven't read Pudlak's paper yet (I hope to in the next couple days), but it seems like it might be a more sophisticated version of the naive greedy construction.

Comment: On a more technical note, [Soowhan Yoon's Ph.D. thesis](https://scholarspace.manoa.hawaii.edu/items/4f569840-b68f-4af9-bd38-f365c88b84b3) studies some computability-theoretic aspects of GS's theorem.